# How many German soldiers were there by the time Nazi Germany surrendered?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

How many German soldiers were out there fighting by the time Nazi Germany surrendered ? (What I mean by surrendered is 8th of may 1945)

I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_Offensive) and it says in early may there were around 800K axis soldiers still in Pragua and it had me thinking, why weren't they in Berlin ?

And how many more were out there and surrendered after Hitler committed suicide ?

I am asking only about soldiers, not considering young boys and old people sent out as soldiers. But those who actually armed and capable of fighting.

Comment: [This page has relevant info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_World_War_II_in_Europe)

Comment: Please clarify your question. When you mean soldiers, are you talking about professional soldiers, Wehrmacht, Luftwaffe, nazis?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question, but the scholars I would probably look at first would be Omer Bartov and Pavel Polian. The former has some very useful charts in his literature, and might touch on this issue (?) in his *Germany's War and the Holocaust*. The latter has excellent stats on a range of related questions - I don't know if he deals with this one though.

Comment: Before that date (may 8) german forces in Italy, Berlin, Holland, north of Germany, Denmark, channel ports and South of Germany already surreder. So only troops in Curland, Norway, Yugoeslavia, Czechia, East Prussia and Austria were still fighting.

Comment: Weren't quite a few bypassed by the rapid advance of the Russians and were thus unable to fall back to Berlin? I know some were left as garrisons in cities that it was obvious would fall, such as Breslau.